# How to remove all table row below particular table row in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, html-table

This is my table :

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="removeFromHere">remove all below tr</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>remove 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>remove  2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>remove 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>remove 4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to remove all the table rows below the following table row

```
 <td class="removeFromHere">remove all below tr</td>
```

what is the best way to do this

I can remove one tr like the following :

```
$('.removeFromHere').parent().remove();
```

But it will only remove the following :

```
 <td class="removeFromHere">remove all below tr</td>
```

> How can I remove all the tr below the particular `tr`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `nextAll()` for that result.

1. You first need to get the `<tr>` element in which there is the element with class `removeFromHere`
2. Then you can use `nextAll()` to remove all the `<tr>` elements those are next to it.

```js
$('.removeFromHere').closest('tr').nextAll('tr').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="removeFromHere">remove all below tr</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>remove 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>remove 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>remove 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>remove 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use index's with the help of greater than selector `:gt()` to achieve that like :

```js
//Get the index of the target tr with class `removeFromHere`
var target_index = $('tr').index($('.removeFromHere').parent());

//Get all the tr's with index greater than 'target_index' then remove them
$('table').find("tr:gt(" + target_index + ")").remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="removeFromHere">remove all below tr</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>remove 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>remove 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>remove 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>remove 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Di you really need more points to be answering such easy questions haha

Comment: @imBlue the point is not on an easy or difficult question. It's the quality of the answer that matters for the OP and for further reference

Comment: @imBlue easy question for you might not be easy for everyone because we are not as smart as you are,

Answer (score 0):

using

```
$('.removeFromHere').parent().remove();
```

won't help, because td's parent is just one particular tr.
I don't use jQuery so I don't really know the syntax, but try using

```
while($('.removeFromHere')parent().next()) {
   $('.removeFromHere')parent().next().remove()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.removeFromHere').parent().nextAll().remove();
```

This will remove all rows after the selected row...

Answer (score 0):

Give your table an id then try removing the last table row until you reach your particular table row.

```
$('#table tr:last').remove();
```

Then you remove the particular tr.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you can use **nextAll()** selector. You can refer document at https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/

Below are the example,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.removeFromHere').parent().nextAll("tr").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="removeFromHere">remove all below tr</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>remove 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>remove 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>remove 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>remove 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```